# I'm trying to set up a bootstrap template for CakePHP3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cakephp-3.0

I'm looking to try and set up the following bootstrap front end template:
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html

I'd like to make this the css/js that is used for the CakePHP but I'm having a bit of trouble finding a plugin that works with CakePHP3.

Any recommendations for a CakePHP Bootstrap Helper Plugin that works with Cake3 would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the new boostrap plugin that can be used with CakePHP 3:

https://github.com/friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui

Answer (score 0):

Currently i can only see this plugin
[Boost cake](http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/bootstrap3.html)

BTW you should learn about add css/js, view, element... 
[Here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html)
So you can implement your template

If you want to build your own form input helper check [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses), And full list template is [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/603f4ee01735f2e8e3c2283540199b4bba70ded7/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L103-L104)